# Is there a Cocoa event equivalent to the carbon event "kEventTextInputUpdateActiveInputArea"?

Tags: cocoa, events

Please let me know if there is a Cocoa event equivalent to [the carbon event "`kEventTextInputUpdateActiveInputArea`"](http://developer.apple.com/legacy/mac/library/documentation/Carbon/reference/Carbon_Event_Manager_Ref/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/kEventTextInputUpdateActiveInputArea) ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No, because Cocoa doesn't use TSM. See the [Cocoa Text System Overview](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/TextArchitecture/).

You generally don't need to use raw events in Cocoa anyway. Whatever you have in mind, it'll probably be easier to implement in delegate methods and/or by subclassing one or more of the relevant classes.

Comment: Thanks Peter, I would like to capture this Carbon event in the Cocoa code. Can this be done? In other words, can Carbon code be embedded in a Cocoa application? Your insight will be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Yes, but it won't do anything unless you are using Carbon text views and text fields. As I said, for Cocoa views, you probably just need to implement a delegate method or something, depending on what you want to do (and you haven't said what you actually want to do by responding to this event).

Comment: My application subclasses the NSView for OpenGL controls.I do not have the benefit of the features provided by the NSTextView. I have implemented the NSTextInputClient protocol which uses the inline input method. When the user types in international text, the inline edit box does not display the text until the "Return" key is hit. Is this the default behavior of the inline input method? Do I need to handle any text event to update the inline textbox? Please let me know if there is any method for updating the display of the inline text window. Thanks

Comment: I don't know. You should ask a question about that.

Comment: Thanks Peter, I appreciate the time you took to provide feedback.